# cannot connect to Microsoft Azure database through odbc

Tags: c++, sql, odbc, azure-sql-database

My odbc uses the following code ( from here : http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/127959-odbc-c-example/) :

odbc.cpp:

```
ODBC_Class::ODBC_Class()
{
ODBC_Class Example;
// Initialize The Return Code Variable
rc = SQL_SUCCESS;
// Allocate An Environment Handle
rc = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &EnvHandle);
// Set The ODBC Application Version To 3.x
if (rc == SQL_SUCCESS)
    rc = SQLSetEnvAttr(EnvHandle, SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION,
    (SQLPOINTER)SQL_OV_ODBC3, SQL_IS_UINTEGER);
// Allocate A Connection Handle
if (rc == SQL_SUCCESS)
    rc = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, EnvHandle, &ConHandle);
}

// Define The Class Destructor
ODBC_Class::~ODBC_Class()
{
  // Free The Connection Handle
  if (ConHandle != NULL)
     SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, ConHandle);
   // Free The Environment Handle
   if (EnvHandle != NULL)
    SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, EnvHandle);
 } 

 // Get the data for one column and return the info in the form
 // of a std::string.  The ODBC driver will make all necessary
 // data conversions from whatever type the data is in the database
// to SQL_CHAR.  You could make this function more comples by 
// getting the return type as it appears in the database then constructing
// a VARIANT object to hold the data.
SQLRETURN ODBC_Class::GetColData(int colnum, string& str)
{
   SQLCHAR buf[255] = { 0 };
   if ((rc = SQLGetData(StmtHandle, colnum, SQL_CHAR, buf, sizeof(buf), NULL)) == SQL_SUCCESS)
       str = reinterpret_cast<char*>(buf);
    return rc;
 }

 //
 // Define The ShowResults() Member Function
 SQLRETURN ODBC_Class::GetResultset()
 {
  // Get all column description
    DescribeColumns();
   // erase anything that's in the colData vector
    colData.clear();
   // fetch a row from the resultset
   while (SQLFetch(StmtHandle) == SQL_SUCCESS)
  {
    // vector of strings to hold the column data
    vector<string> col;
    string data;
    // column counter
    int i = 1;
    // get the data for each column and add it to 
    // the col vector
    while (GetColData(i, data) == SQL_SUCCESS)
    {
        col.push_back(data);
        ++i; // increment the column number
    }
    // add column data to the colData vector
    colData.push_back(col);
   }
  return SQL_SUCCESS;
}

// Get the description for one column in the resultset.
// This was made a seprate function to simplify the coding
SQLRETURN  ODBC_Class::Describe(ColDescription& c)
{
   return SQLDescribeCol(StmtHandle, c.colNumber,
     c.colName, sizeof(c.colName), &c.nameLen,
       &c.dataType, &c.colSize, &c.decimalDigits, &c.nullable);
}

// Get the description for all the columns in the resultset.
void ODBC_Class::DescribeColumns()
{
   ColDescription c;
   c.colNumber = 1;
   cols.clear();
   while (Describe(c) == SQL_SUCCESS)
   {
    cols.push_back(c);
    ++c.colNumber;
 }

}
```

In my main file I execute it with this code  ( it's again the same code sample from the website above)

```
void Game::sqlConnection(const char *select) {

    SQLCHAR DBName[] = "Driver=SQL Server Native Client 11.0;Server=tcp:myserver.ctp.database.windows.net;Database=PandemicMain;Uid=concordia;Pwd=University4;";
    SQLCHAR SQLStmt[255] = { 0 };

    SQLRETURN rc = SQL_SUCCESS;

    if (Example.ConHandle != NULL)

   {

       rc = SQLConnect(Example.ConHandle, DBName, SQL_NTS, (SQLCHAR *) "", SQL_NTS, (SQLCHAR *) "", SQL_NTS);

       // Allocate An SQL Statement Handle 

        rc = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, Example.ConHandle,  &Example.StmtHandle);

        rc = SQLExecDirect(Example.StmtHandle, SQLStmt, SQL_NTS);

      if (rc == SQL_SUCCESS)

      {

        // Define A SELECT SQL Statement  

            strcpy((char *)SQLStmt,  select);

         // Prepare And Execute The SQL Statement  

           rc = SQLExecDirect(Example.StmtHandle, SQLStmt, SQL_NTS);

          // Display The Results Of The SQL Query  
          if (!rc == SQL_SUCCESS) {
              cout << "*************************** failed ***************" 
       << endl;
           }
          if (rc == SQL_SUCCESS)

         {

             Example.GetResultset();




            // At this point you would want to do something  

            // with the resultset, such as display it.  

        }

    }

    // Free The SQL Statement Handle  

    if (Example.StmtHandle != NULL)

        SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, Example.StmtHandle);

    // Disconnect From The Northwind Sample Database  
        rc = SQLDisconnect(Example.ConHandle);

   }



 }
```

I know there is this site: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn630643.aspx but I was wondering if it was possible to do it with this code. I was able to connect to my Local DB but I need my teammates to be able to run the code from their house so I hosted my db on azure.

When running the above code with the string as given,  I end up with a "-2" SQLRETURN from the SqlConnect(). ( only occurs with the azure db so I'm assuming I'm not connecting to it right)

Any insight on how to make this code run or is it futile ?

Thank you

Comment: If anyone uses the tutorial above and is new to cpp ( like me) and is trying to understand why, SQLConnect takes a username and password. I should've looked deeper.

Answer (score 0):

Also keep in mind that Azure SQL has an IP Address based firewall that will require you to whitelist your team's home routers (which will probably change semi-frequently):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-firewall-configure